# App crashes when i tap iphone back button

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

Hello World:) I have a rate button in my game, which goes to appstore when I click it. But if I tap little back button above the iphone, my app crashes. This code I have, when I go to appstore app:

```
internal func rate(appId: String, completion: @escaping ((_ success: Bool) -> ())) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com") else {
        completion(false)
        return
    }
    guard #available(iOS 10, *) else {
        completion(UIApplication.shared.openURL(url))
        return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: completion)
}
```

in completionHandler I have:

```
internal func rateUsButtonTouched() {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    menuSceneNodeDelegate?.rate(appId: "appID", completion: {_ in 
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    })
}
```

These both of codes go in delegate. Can't have any idea what problem is!

Comment: What does your call stack say?

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xff769abc). Nothing in console, besides this: (lldb)

Comment: You should probably start not with where you came from, but what runs when your app regains the foreground. e.g. check AppDelegate methods.

Comment: Graham, I got nothing in AppDelegate methods. Can't grasp what's going on.

Comment: I've fixed this crash bug. My app crashes, because of the button click sound.